# Can I send Ctrl+C to Android terminal from Windows Powershell?

Tags: adb, windows

Adb shell should let me Ctrl+C to exit a command like `top`. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work in Windows. Is there a workaround?

Comment: any solution about it?

Comment: What doesn't let you use Ctrl+C? Powershell? cmd.exe?